# Rackspace connecting to a server using Pyrax in python

Tags: python, cloud, rackspace-cloud, pyrax

I have recently started using [pyrax](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax#pyrax), the python binding for the Rackspace API. I have a test account on Rackspace and a server running there. Using my username and api_key I can authenticate and list all the servers found in that region.

How do I connect to a particular server given its name, server id, IPv4 address, IPv6 address, flavor etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyrax is specifically used to interact with the Rackspace Cloud API in provisioning the resources.

A different library would be required if you wanted to connect to the server via SSH. Check out something like http://www.lag.net/paramiko/